# Query huge data in csv

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Apologies for asking such a dumb and basic question, I'm in part of exploring the AWS cloud stack.
 I'm having an excel file with 11000 rows, and when I tried to upload them to DynamoDB, it gave me throughput error(may be because of the huge volume).

Now I want to query this data by storing it onto an s3 bucket or any other form. Usually my approach will be (if the data is of up to 200 rows), upload the data onto dynamodb -> create an apigateway endpoint -> trigger the endpoint with the required parameters.

But now since the data is really vast, I'm unable to know on how can I do this.

Can someone please let me know what can be the best alternative of DynamoDB or should it be better I stick to DynamoDB itself?

Thanks

Comment: do you use aws sdk for uploading data to DynamoDB programmatically? if so, you could use throttling to insert data into DynamoDB more slowly (I mean, for example, after each ten insert operations sleep/wait for several seconds), and this will prevent throughput error. To be able to upload more data in a short period of time you need to increase write capacity units (in web console select your table >> Capacity tab >> change read and write capacity units according to your needs).
it's also unclear for me what do you need to do with data stored in DynamoDB.

Comment: Why do you wish to use DynamoDB? What do you mean by "query this data"? Do you just want to run SQL queries on it, or use it via Lambda? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Unless these rows are very, very wide, this is actually not that much data. 11k rows is tiny. Push it into MySQL or go the S3/Athena route.

Answer (score 1):

A good option is:

- Save the data in S3 in CSV format (feel free to zip it to save space)
- Use [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-athena-interactive-sql-queries-for-data-in-amazon-s3/) to query it directly out of S3